# Descobrir quantos produtos preciso vender até atingir a meta

Tags: sql

Essa é uma pergunta que exige raciocínio logico, mas vamos lá.

Como fazer em SQL, pode ser função, uma forma de descobrir quantos produtos preciso vender para atingir a meta.

Por exemplo:

Vendi um determinado produto e preciso saber quantos produtos precisam ser vendidos para chegar a exatos x reais sendo que seu valor, do produto, tem variação de mínima e máxima.

A quantidade de produto deve ser a menor possível até chegar a x reais e cada produto não pode ter valor inferior ao valor mínimo e superior ao valor máximo.

**Exemplo prático:**

```
Meta: Vender R$ 90,00 reais

Vendi R$ 10,00 reais
Faltam R$ 80,00 reais

Valor minimo do produto: R$ 10,00 reais
Valor Maximo: R$ 20,00 reais

**Resposta**: Faltam  4 produtos de R$ 20,00 reais.
```

**Outro exemplo:**

```
Meta: Vender R$ 100,00 reais

Vendi R$ 10,00 reais
Faltam R$ 90,00 reais

Valor minimo do produto: R$ 10,00 reais
Valor Maximo: R$ 20,00 reais

**Resposta**: Faltam 4 produtos de R$ 20 reais e 1 produto de R$ 10,00 reais.
```

**Mais outro exemplo:**

```
Meta: vender R$ 19,00 reais

Vendi R$ 2,00 reais.
Faltam R$ 17,00 reais

Valor minimo do produto: R$ 2,00 reais
Valor Maximo: R$ 6,00 reais


**Resposta**: Faltam 2 produtos de R$ 6,00 reais e 2 produtos de R$ 2,5 reais.
```

A função terá 4 parâmetros de entrada e uma de saída: 
Entrada: Meta, valor faltante, valor mínimo, valor máximo. 
Saída: Resposta

No caso de for impossível atingir a meta informar que com base do valor mínimo e máximo não é possível.

Comment: Dependendo do numero de produtos você pode ter  milhares de maneiras diferentes de atingir a meta. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Você já desenvolveu algum código ?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Não entendi o seu comentário.

Comment: @Gumball Ainda não

Comment: @Leandro qual o banco?

Comment: Pesquise por Algoritmo da Mochila   https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila

Comment: @Sorack Sql Server

Comment: Se você postar o seu modelo de dados fica mais fácil ajudar

Comment: @Daniel, deve-se priorizar a menor quantidade de produtos possível. No caso do seu exemplo seria 1 produto de 10 reais.